# DependencyProperty as trigger value

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I am trying to stylize my application `Button` with custom `DependencyProperty`

The dependency declaration:

```
public static class Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundHoverProperty;

    static Button()
    {
        BackgroundHoverProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "BackgroundHover",
            typeof(Brush),
            typeof(Button),
            new PropertyMetadata(Application.Current.FindResource("Mask.Hover")));
    }

    public static Brush GetBackgroundHover(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Brush)obj.GetValue(BackgroundHoverProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBackgroundHover(DependencyObject obj, Brush value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BackgroundHoverProperty, value);
    }
}
```

The button style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Border.Default}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Foreground.Default}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="controls:Button.BackgroundHover" Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

the button template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
        <Border
            x:Name="Border"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
        <ContentPresenter
            x:Name="Content"
            RecognizesAccessKey="True"
            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
            ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
            Focusable="False" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter
                Property="Background"
                TargetName="Border"
                Value="{Binding (controls:Button.BackgroundHover), // <--- Here is the binding
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I can't find out what I am doing wrong.

Edit: I have also tried `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` and still no result.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Are you getting an error? Is there any binding errors in the output window? Is it just not showing the mouse over state?

Comment: No i don't get any error, just that when i mouse over the button, it does not change to blue. Also i noticed that clicking becomes very unreliable when i do use that particular binding while if i replace it with a hard coded color for instance, it works perfectly.

Comment: @reonZ: You should also remove `StaticResource Border.Default` and any other static resources from your example since you don't include these resources in the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Change `{RelativeSource Self}` to `{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`:

```
Value="{Binding (controls:Button.BackgroundHover),
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't change anything, also tried to do `{RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}` while trying to remove `TargetName=Border` every time.

Comment: @reonZ: It works just fine for me, i.e. the buttons turns blue on mouse over.

Comment: I don't know what to say, i copied my code directly here.

Comment: @reonZ: What is `Mask.Hover` and how do you map the `controls` namespace for example?

Comment: `Mask.Hover` is a `SolidColorBrush` but i also tried removing the default metadata anyways. And i simply put a `xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyProject.Controls"` in the `ResourceDictionary` header.